# Rails respond with JBuilder (AngularJS)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, angularjs, jbuilder

i have a simple application to snooker league and i have a action add_player in LeaguesController. My client (AngularJS) call this action and i want to respond with json format using JBuilder. This working fine:

```
 def add_player
   ...

   render :json => @league.players.to_json(:only => [ :id, :firstname, :lastname, :max_break, :email ])
end
```

But when i delete this line and add:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html 
  format.json 
end
```

i have this error:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (
  Missing template leagues/add_player, 
  application/add_player 
  with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb,    :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder, :haml]}. 
  Searched in:
* "/home/daniel/SitesWWW/snookerLeague/app/views"
):
app/controllers/leagues_controller.rb:67:in `add_player'
```

Of course i have file add_player.json.jbuilder:

```
json.players @league.players do |player|
  json.id player.id
  json.firstname player.firstname.capitalize if player.firstname
  json.lastname player.lastname.capitalize if player.lastname
  json.email player.email
  json.max_break player.max_break
end
```

So, what i should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice in your error message `:formats=>[:html]` this indicates to me it is trying to render add_player.html.erb and not your jbuilder template.

To verify this, try changing the calling code and append `.json` to the url which will force the format to be json.

You can also specify a default of json on your routes and not include it in the url:

```
resources :leagues, defaults: { format: :json } do
  member do
    post :add_player
  end
end
```

see also: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#defining-defaults

Comment: Change routes helps. Thanks.